# convert images from python to c# - Image sizes are way too different

Tags: c#, .net, python, bitmap

I am trying to convert images from python to c#, the images which python has created are much smaller in size and images which .net is creating are much larger in size. I do not want to reduce the quality of images, not sure why it is happening.

here is the python code.

```
        if img.mode != "RGB":
        img = img.convert("RGB")
        img = img.resize((width,height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        resampled_image_name = os.path.splitext(resampled_image_name)[0] + "." + format
        img.save(resampled_image_name)
```

and this is my c# code

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
        }

        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(resampledImageName);
        resampledImageName = resampledImageName.Replace(info.Extension, "." + format);

        bitmap.Save(@resampledImageName);
```

Comment: its queue of images, they are in different formats, but mostly they are jpg and gifs.

Comment: if you say "size" do you mean the file size ? If yes: do you store them in the same format in python and c# ?

Comment: yes, file size and yes they are stored in same format, it might be because of RGB mode in python and i dont know if i can configure that in c#

Comment: You aren't showing the Save code in the C# version. Please show that code. `Bitmap.Save` will save it as a BMP unless you specify which format to save it in.

Comment: i have updated the code with save method, but for your comment (vcsjones). I am providing file format.

Comment: You say you're providing the file format, but your code does not reflect that. Calling `bitmap.Save(filename)` is going to save the file as a BMP. If you want to save as GIF, you have to write `bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif)`. How much larger in size is "much larger"?

Comment: Many thanks Jim, even if the filename is reflecting that its Gif or JPEG, will not make any difference.

e.g will following two simple lines produce different results?
        
    bitmap.Save("filename.gif");
    bitmap.Save("filename", ImageFormat.Gif);

Many thanks.

Comment: @zish: `bitmap.Save("filename.gif")` will save the file as a BMP. To save it as a GIF, you *must* specify it, as in your second example.